# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'certifi.core'

Tags: python, speech-recognition, pyttsx3

I am making an personal assistant named Kyle using SpeechRecognition and pyttsx3. I was trying to convert my python file to an executable using pyinstaller.

I type in:

```
pyinstaller --onefile --add-binary "C:\Users\Dr. Puffyapple\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\site-packages\pywin32_system32/pythoncom36.dll;." kyle_backend.py
```

Everything goes smoothly, but when I open the .exe file this error appears:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "kyle_backend.py", line 2, in <module>
    File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 476, in exec_module
    File "pywhatkit\__init__.py", line 12, <module>
    File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 476, in exec_module
    File "pywhatkit\handwriting.py", line 1, in <module>
    File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 476, in exec_module
    File "requests\__init__.py", line 133, in <module>
    File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 476, in exec_module
    File "requests\utils.py", line 26, in <module>
    File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 476, in exec_module
    File "requests\certs.py", line 15, in <module>
    File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 476, in exec_module
    File "certifi\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'certifi.core'
[31340] Failed to execute script 'kyle_backend' due to unhandled exception!
```

[See error here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vk5S9.png)

I really hope someone can help! Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you haven't installed the certifi module. Depending on what version of python you're on is going to depend on what you're going to use to install it.

Running **pip3 install certifi** should fix this problem!